# vim comment syntax coloring that resets based on columns value without linebreaks

Tags: vim, syntax

I work with FITS files that do not use linkbreaks.
Here is a snippet of one such file:

```
SIMPLE  =                    T / file does conform to FITS standard             BITPIX  =                    8 / number of bits per data pixel                  NAXIS   =                    0 / number of data axes                            EXTEND  =                    T / FITS dataset may contain extensions            COMMENT   FITS (Flexible Image Transport System) format is defined in 'AstronomyCOMMENT   and Astrophysics', volume 376, page 359; bibcode: 2001A&A...376..359H TELESCOP= 'TELESCOP'           / Telescope (mission) name                       INSTRUME= 'INST    '           / Instrument name                                OBS_ID  = '00000000000'        / Observation ID                                 TARG_ID =                00000 / Target ID                                      SEG_NUM =                    0 / Segment number                                 TIMESYS = 'TT      '           / time measured from
```

When I view these files I use `set numberwidth=6` and `set columns=86`

```
SIMPLE  =                    T / file does conform to FITS standard            
BITPIX  =                    8 / number of bits per data pixel                  
NAXIS   =                    0 / number of data axes                            
EXTEND  =                    T / FITS dataset may contain extensions            
COMMENT   FITS (Flexible Image Transport System) format is defined in 'Astronomy
COMMENT   and Astrophysics', volume 376, page 359; bibcode: 2001A&A...376..359H
TELESCOP= 'TELESCOP'           / Telescope (mission) name                  
INSTRUME= 'INST    '           / Instrument name                              
OBS_ID  = '00000000000'        / Observation ID                                 
TARG_ID =                00000 / Target ID                                      
SEG_NUM =                    0 / Segment number                                 
TIMESYS = 'TT      '           / time measured from
```

The issue is `syntax match myComment " / .*$"` obviously does not respect `set columns` and it highlights everything after the first comment.  I want it to know that the first comment can only extend up to column 80, the second comment ends at column 160 and so on.

### EDIT:

I've created a vim syntax file:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif

syn match fitsComment1 " / .*\%80c"
hi link fitsComment1 Comment
syn match fitsComment2 "COMMENT.*\%400c"
hi link fitsComment2 Comment
syn match fitsComment2 "COMMENT.*\%480c"
hi link fitsComment2 Comment

let c1 = 80
let c2 = 160
let c = 1
while c <= 8
    let regex = '" \%>' . c1 . 'c/ .*\%' . c2 . 'c"'
    execute 'syn match fitsComment2 '.regex
    hi link fitsComment2 Comment
    let c1 += 80
    let c2 += 80
    let c += 1
endwhile

let b:current_syntax = "fits"
```

This file produces the desired highlighting with some caveats:
"Multiline" comments start with `COMMENT`.
I added

```
syn match fitsComment2 "COMMENT.*\%400c"
hi link fitsComment2 Comment
syn match fitsComment2 "COMMENT.*\%480c"
hi link fitsComment2 Comment
```

that explicitly handle them in my example but it is not a true fix because I don't always know where these multiline comments will take place.

Is there a way I can do this without the `while` loop?  Looping makes reading the files very slow (these files can be rather long).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
syn match myComment1 " / .*\%80c"
syn match myComment2 " \%>80c/ .*\%180c"
hi link myComment1 Comment 
hi link myComment2 Comment
```

This uses the `\%c` regex atom to anchor the regular expression to specific columns. You would have to create a new syn match rule, until all your columns that you need are covered. Note, the second comment rule is explicitly anchored to start after the 80th column, otherwise it would go from the first comment char until the last (greedy matches).

Comment: I've created a syntax file using your suggestion and updated my question.  I also have multiline comments that pose an issue and my current method via looping is very resource intensive.